The COM library for checking Windows updates search does not work according to the C++ MFC source code
Environment: Visual Studio 2015, MFC
Issue:
hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    jvResult[_T("result")] = JsonValue::number((int)ISPT_ResultEnum::ISPTResult_Fail);
    jvResult[_T("detail")][_T("error_log")] = JsonValue::string(l10n(IDS_INSPCT_ERRLOG_COM_INIT_FAIL).operator LPCWSTR());

    return;
}

When this code is used, the return value of IUpdateSearcher::EndSearch is WU_E_WU_DISABLED.
The code never enters the if statement.
However, if I change
jvResult[_T("detail")][_T("error_log")] = JsonValue::string(l10n(IDS_INSPCT_ERRLOG_COM_INIT_FAIL).operator LPCWSTR());

to
jvResult[_T("detail")][_T("error_log")] = JsonValue::string(_T("Initial Fail"));

the Windows Update Search function works correctly.
Could you help me understand why this is happening?
CString strMsg = l10n(IDS_INSPCT_ERRLOG_COM_INIT_FAIL);
 BCGPCustomMessageBox(strMsg, theApp.m_nLanguage, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
 hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
 if (FAILED(hr)) 
{ 
jvResult[_T("result")] = JsonValue::number((int)ISPT_ResultEnum::ISPTResult_Fail);
 jvResult[_T("detail")][_T("error_log")] = JsonValue::string(l10n(IDS_INSPCT_ERRLOG_COM_INIT_FAIL).operator LPCWSTR()); 
return; 
} 

This also works correctly.

CString strMsg = l10n(IDS_INSPCT_ERRLOG_COM_INIT_FAIL);
BCGPCustomMessageBox(strMsg, theApp.m_nLanguage, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
jvResult[_T("result")] = JsonValue::number((int)ISPT_ResultEnum::ISPTResult_Fail);
jvResult[_T("detail")][_T("error_log")] = JsonValue::string(l10n(IDS_INSPCT_ERRLOG_COM_INIT_FAIL).operator LPCWSTR());
return;
}
This also works correctly.

What's the relation between the code you show which is barely understandable and COM and/or Windows Update?

I thought they were related because the WMI function IUpdateSearcher performs the Windows update search operation. In my opinion, calling CoInitialize and then immediately calling the CHString::operator LPCWSTR method, which is part of WMI, seems to affect WMI.

"CHString::operator LPWSTR method which is part of WMI" ? What WMI are you talking about?

If CoInitialize is failing then you'll never even create any COM objects. Regardless, we can't help you if you don't provide more context. You mention IUpdateSearcher and WMI, both of which are completely absent from the tiny code sample you've provided. At a bare minimum you need to provide a minimal reproducible example.
